# Count lowercase letters till the input is string

Tags: c

I wrote a short code in C which count the lowercase letters (only letters) and it'll stop working when I enter a number or something else. Here is the code:

```
char letter;
int num=0;
do
    if(islower(letter = getchar()))
       num++;
while(isalpha(letter));
printf("%d", num);
return 0;
```

My problem is that it isn't working properly (only print "1" as result).
And it has to be stopped when the next character isn't alphabetical letter. Not sure that part is right.

Any idea what did I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Why did you tag this c++? You're asking for plain c, am I right? Please remove the tag.

Comment: Show your inputs.

Comment: It is working for me, I run it on Visual Studio 2013 and its working perfect.

Comment: You need to store the return value of `isalpha()` in a separate `int` variable and check it something like `while(ret_val != 0);`.
Now here I am clueless as why `isalpha()` not working even if I used it like `while(isalpha(letter) != 0)` and worked flawlessly when stored the return variable in a separate variable.
@BLUEPIXY do you have any idea about this strange behavior?

Comment: Entered one character at a time.  ?

Comment: Yes, I entered one char at a time.

Answer (score 0):

what's about this?

```
char letter;
int num=0;
while (isalpha(letter = getchar())) {
    if (islower(letter)) num++;
}
printf("%d", num);
return 0;
```

> And it has to be stopped when the next character isn't alphabetical letter.

keyboard input can be buffered - not processing until Enter be pressed

> only print "1" as result

can you write some examples of inputed in console caused to "1" output?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, after inputting a single character, the subsequent call to `getchar()` returns a newline character, as the `'\n'` from the return key is buffered. So, the first iteration of

```
 do
    if (islower(letter = getchar()))
        num++;
 while (isalpha(letter));
```

works, but the program displays "1" as the `islower()` call returns false when the newline is processed.

To fix this, use a `while` loop to eat away the extra newlines. You could do it as such:

```
do {
    while ((letter = getchar()) == '\n')
        ;

    if (islower(letter))
        num++;
} while (isalpha(letter));
```